# Passing one widget value to another widget in Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

How can one pass a value obtained in one widget to another? For example, say I have two functions

```
def update_dataset(attrname, old, new):
    dataset = dataset_select.value
    n_samples = int(samples_slider.value)

    data1 = get_dataset(dataset, n_samples)

def update_slider(attrname, old, new):
    n_samples = int(samples_slider.value)

    data2 = get_ends(data1, n_samples)
    source_chart.data = dict(x=data2['aspects'].tolist(), y=data2['importance'].values)
```

The first function (update_dataset) grabs a new dataset, and I want to pass this dataset to the second function (update_slider) to use in the line

```
data2 = get_ends(data1, n_samples)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you provide some more code behind this? But it should be definitely possible to get the value of one widget and passing that to another.

Comment: @Okonomiyaki, thanks for your help these last couple of days. It seems hard to find good examples of these kinds of things online. The current version of the code is here:

    http://pastebin.com/b9Zs53jj

I can't upload the two input files to github because they're too big, but if you need them let me know. There's an additional text box widget in the code that currently doesn't do anything, but will in the future -- so just ignore that. Thanks again!

Comment: If my answers helped you and were correct, could you upvote and mark as correct. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example with two data sets, you need to set each to be a source. The first button just gives you x and y = a list of one random number each. The second button then takes a random sample from 0 to max(x), max(y) and plots it.
Hopefully that gives you the template to do what you want?

```
import random
from bokeh.layouts import layout
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models.widgets import Button
from bokeh.plotting import figure, ColumnDataSource



""" widget updating function """

def update_button1():
    # get random data on source 1
    newdata = data_reform()
    source1.data = newdata

def update_button2():
    # allocates source 2 data to data 1
    data = source1.data
    newdata2 = expand_data(data)
    source2.data = newdata2

""" create buttons and allocate call back functions """
button1 = Button(label="Press here to update source1", button_type="success")
button2 = Button(label="Press here to update source2 from source1 data",
                 button_type="success")
button1.on_click(update_button1)
button2.on_click(update_button2)    

""" example functions that operate on our data """
def data_reform():
    newdata = {'x':[random.randint(40,100)]*10, 'y':[random.randint(4,100)]*10}
    return newdata

def expand_data(data):
    max_x = max(data['x'])
    max_y = max(data['y'])
    if(max_x <20):
        max_x = 20
    if(max_y <20):
        max_y = 20
    data = {'x':random.sample(range(0,max_x),20),
                 'y':random.sample(range(0,max_y),20)}
    return data

source1 = ColumnDataSource({'x':[40]*10,'y':[30]*10})
source2 = ColumnDataSource({'x':[0]*20,'y':[20]*20})

""" example plots to show data changing """
figure1 = figure(plot_width=250,
             plot_height=200,
             x_axis_label='x',
             y_axis_label='y')
figure2 = figure(plot_width=250,
             plot_height=200,
             x_axis_label='x',
             y_axis_label='y')
figure1.vbar(x='x', width=0.5, bottom=0,top='y',source=source1,
             color="firebrick")
figure2.vbar(x='x', width=0.5, bottom=0,top='y',source=source2,
             color="firebrick")

layout = layout([[figure1, figure2, button1, button2]])
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```